# How to pick a right hardware configuration setup(server) for MERN stack

Tags: configuration, serverspec

I'm learning programming(MERN stack) and along with that basic DevOps(linux, containers etc). I've read a lot about software configuration setups(with NGINX, and without, etc), but can't find anywhere regards how well the MERN stack will behave on different server hardware configuration setups.

I will probably host my app on Linode, for various reasons(price, anti-ddos etc), but I guess it will applicable for alike services too(digital ocean etc).

So, is there a way to approximately know before deploying, how much my app will need resources? Are there any assumptions I can make regards MongoDB's usage(of RAM, for example?), for example?

Any info will be valuable for me, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is for your learning, it shouldn't tax your hardware incredibly. If you are hosting I would with a free student account if you can. But if you have a linux laptop all of this should work well on it. You're not writing apps that are getting 10,000's of connections and transforming complex data. If you had an enterprise app I would indeed split off the DB from the frontend etc.